# Native virtual keypad (Next and Done)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, keyboard, native

I am creating a Login module. On focus of username it shows go in keys and next on top of keys. But I want native virtual keypad. As native does not show previous and next keys on top of keypad. it changes the text of same key as next and go (done).

Comment: Which version of jqm you are using? In the old versions, there was a known issue for this.

Comment: Cordova 3.0.0 and jquerymobile 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar flag in the config.xml file to do this.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html#iOS%20Configuration